# Full authentication exception in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hello I have following Security config file.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http     
        .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)        
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/myservices/**/**").permitAll()            
            .antMatchers("/knowndata").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/guidata/**").permitAll()                        
            .antMatchers("/textdata/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .httpBasic();

        http.csrf().disable();      


    }
```

and the following CORSFilter

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-auth-token,authorization, content-type, xsrf-token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else { 
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

Still I get Full authentication required exception when accessing the myservices.

Comment: Do you send an `Authorization` header within request?

Comment: No I do not send any header with it. Any example ?

Comment: According your configuration, you need a http basic authentication to access applicatio.
Authorization: Basic base64encoded(username:password)